# AB test - Is it okay to use a result with a low confidence level

Tags: expected-value, confidence-interval, ab-test

Suppose you conduct an A/B test of 10,000 views for each of version A and B, but the results take 3 months to capture. Despite a small number of views, achieving a goal (converting a "view" to a payment) is very valuable.

Group A has 104 goals, and group B has 96 goals. The result is not statistically significant; you conclude with 72% confidence that group A is better.

The problem is that this is a competitive market, and time is of the essence. While you could wait another 3 months to determine with certainty whether layout A is better than layout B, you could also be testing the next big change during this time.

Assuming you have a list of other improvements each with an expected change of goals in the range of -7% to +9%, is your expected outcome higher to keep iterating and move on to the next test (A vs C), or spending another 3 months confirming that A is significantly better than B?

Comment: +1 The larger and more important question is whether you should be conducting hypothesis tests at all. Other methods, including sequential testing and quality-control monitoring, might be better adapted to what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @whuber any recommended resources on sequential testing?